# Why are my "centered" objects slightly off-center in my RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, gravity

I wanted to make two equally-sized radio buttons with a custom background, text, and an image to the right of the text. Because of how different these are from a standard "Button", I made them using a clickable "RelativeLayout".

The text and the image are of different heights, but I want each one to be centered vertically in the button. I also want the combination of the text+image to be centered horizontally in the button. This second part is what I'm having trouble with; it's off-center, close to the left side. In the image below, the left side is what I want, but the right side is what's happening. The image on one of the buttons (the one with the longer text) is resized to be smaller, too... Though there is still plenty of space on the right side of the button.

[image: What I want is on the left, and what's happening is on the right.]

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_textview"
            android:text="@string/button_label"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceButton"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
            android:id="@+id/button_imageview"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/my_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_textview">
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        ... same thing for the second button ...
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was adding

```
android:paddingRight="0dip"
```

strangely enough, even though I didn't put any padding there in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Use this as your button:

```
<LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              >
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:text="MyButton"/>
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
               android:src="@drawable/my_image"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, you can place it in other parent views. To apply layout attributes to above button, place those attributes in the outer `<LinearLayout>` tag of above button.

Alternative:

You can set custom images to be drawn on sides(Left,Right,Top,Bottom) of a `TextView` using attributes like:
`android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_image"`

Comment: That didn't change anything, but thanks. I was hopeful for a moment there. My reason for not using drawableRight is that it draws it on the right edge of the button, not immediately to the right of the text.

Comment: Can you update the layout you are using now in your question ?